# JPA locks and database isolation levels

Tags: jpa

Is there any mutual influence between JPA locks (optimistic/pessimistic) and database isolation levels (in example http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html)?

EJB3.2 Spec (8.3.2 "Isolation levels") says that Bean Provider is responsible for setting isolation level of transaction, so generally I shouldn't care, but anyway I am still confused. In example in PostgreSQL, according to mentioned source, the default isolation level is "read commited". Does this mean, that when I do not lock any entity, the transaction isolation level will be still "read commited"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having `@Version` column on your entities and using no locking (equivalent of using `LockModeType.NONE`) you are implicitly working with READ_COMMITED isolation. This is achieved in the JPA layer because all updates are usually deferred until commit time or `OptimisticLockException` is thrown is case of an update conflict (I'm still assuming no explicit locking).

> It assumes ... that writes to the database
>   will typically occur only when the flush method has been invoked—whether explicitly by the application,
>   or by the persistence provider runtime in accordance with the flush mode setting

On the database layer, JPA specification also assumes you have READ_COMMITED isolation.

> It assumes that the databases to
>   which persistence units are mapped will be accessed by the implementation using read-committed isolation
>   (or a vendor equivalent in which long-term read locks are not held)

Of course manual flush/refresh, queries and flush type modes  (`AUTO`, `COMMIT`) complicates the situation. Also 2nd level and query cache configuration might play a role. However with all defaults, JPA READ_COMMITED behaves pretty predictably and as a rule of thumb it is safe to accompany it with READ_COMMITED isolation at the db level.

In order to achieve REPETABLE_READ with JPA you have to use locks (but that's another story).

> Lock modes are intended to provide a facility that enables the effect of “repeatable read” semantics

Comment: Only a partial answer and a bit unclear ... Could you update the answer and say how exactly calls such as `connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.READ_UNCOMMITTED);` differ from calls like `entityManager.lock(entity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);`? Is one implemented using the other? Which is implemented in code and which using DB provider (e.g. MySQL) locks?